# Why h:inputText doesn't use default locale for number conversion?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, locale, converters

I have some `h:inpuText` fields to hold numbers. All decimal values are shown with "." as delimiter, although I have the following entry in *faces-config.xml*:

```
<locale-config>
     <default-locale>de</default-locale>
</locale-config>
```

and the call

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale()
```

returns "de".

However, if I add an `<f:convertNumber/>` to my `h:inputText` the correct decimal delimiter is shown (e.g. 6,2 instead of 6.2).

Do I have to add the `f:convertNumber` to all of my input fields or is there a way without?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format is the `toString` format for the floating point number.

Consider the bean property `foo`:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
  private double foo;
  public double getFoo() { return foo; }
  public void setFoo(double foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

`inputText` doesn't have any direct support for number types; it will be given an object (`java.lang.Double`) and call `toString` on it on output. On a form submit, the browser sends a `String` and the Expression Language coerces it back to a double as per its rules for type coercion (see the EL spec).

For more complex logic, a converter is required. This is a powerful model, as you can convert to/from any type without requiring the input/output control to support the conversion.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I always thought that a numberConverter is automatically used for inputText fields with `value="#{bean.someNumberType}"`